# Elastic Search echo jvm_options_parser_failed was unexpected at this time

Tags: elasticsearch

**Problem:**

> \Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe" -cp "!ES_CLASSPATH!"
>   "org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser"
>   "!ES_JVM_OPTIONS!" || echo jvm_options_parser_failed")' was unexpected
>   at this time.

**Solution**
change below line in elasticsearch.bat

> set "ES_JVM_OPTIONS=%ES_PATH_CONF%\jvm.options" @setlocal for /F
>   "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`CALL %JAVA% -cp "!ES_CLASSPATH!"
>   "org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser"
>   "!ES_JVM_OPTIONS!" ^|^| echo jvm_options_parser_failed`) do set
>   JVM_OPTIONS=%%a @endlocal & set
>   "MAYBE_JVM_OPTIONS_PARSER_FAILED=%JVM_OPTIONS%" & set
>   ES_JAVA_OPTS=%JVM_OPTIONS:${ES_TMPDIR}=!ES_TMPDIR!% %ES_JAVA_OPTS%

Answer (score 1):

```
(\`CALL %JAVA% -cp "!ES_CLASSPATH!" "org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser" "!ES_JVM_OPTIONS!" ^|^| echo jvm_options_parser_failed\`)
```

That was the solution but this 1 is more accurate.
I struggled for 30 minutes using suggested solution.

Answer (score 1):

I faced issue due to Java 32 bit which was pointing to Program Files(x86) folder. Changed to 64 bit JDK 8.Now it is working

Comment: Worked like a charm.